# How to do post-hoc contrasts on within factor depending on certain between groups in SPSS?

Tags: anova, repeated-measures, spss

Here are my experimental factors:

- within-factor (two levels): time1, time2.
- between factor (four levels): 4 groups.

I want to test *specific post-hoc contrasts* comparing:

1. group1: time1 vs. time2
2. group2: time1 vs. time2
3. group3: time1 vs. time2
4. group4: time1 vs. time2

to determine if and which group the time factor affects.

SPSS *only* provides an overall within effect for time averaging 4 groups. Moreover, SPSS *only* provides post-hoc contrasts for the between groups averaging time

How can I do my specific contrasts?